# What is the equivalent of these Linux IPTABLES lines for macOS High Sierra?

Tags: macos, terminal, network

I am working for fun on a DOSBOX experiment to get Windows 3.11 WFG to connect to the internet through PPP and Trumpet Winsock. So far, with this script (https://github.com/knightmare2600/oldschool/blob/master/WFW/dosbox_ppp.sh) I got it to work on my RPi3 running Raspbian and DOSBOX 0.74, and I could hilariously view the google page (as well as low-bandwidth versions of some pages) on Internet Explorer 5.0! But for this script to work I had to add these lines after enabling ip forwarding:

```
# Allow established connections

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Masquerade

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Now, I want to do the same on my macbook air running macOS High Sierra. But I can't understand how to make the equivalent of these particular 3 lines for macOS. Anyone knows how or can direct me to the way?

This is where I got everything for this project: 
https://mainframed767.tumblr.com/post/164524161692/dosbox-and-trumpet-winsock-together-at-last

Comment: For somebody familiar with IP and such but not familiar with `iptables`: what do these commands do?

Comment: Please keep the code formatting, the commands are very hard to read otherwise

Comment: @nohillside: these commands apparently help with port forwarding in some way I can't clearly explain - I am not familiar with ip forwarding either. What I have is a dosbox running Windows 3.11 For Workgroups and Trumpet Winsock to connect it to the internet, but dosbox needs a virtual serial port for it to happen (through PPP and socat). I got it working on Linux, but my daily computer is a macbook and I can't really get it to work there.

Comment: This is the link where I got everything for this project: https://mainframed767.tumblr.com/post/164524161692/dosbox-and-trumpet-winsock-together-at-last#notes

Comment: Not really an answer, but you could launch a Linux VM on your mba and uses the same method as for your rpi

Comment: Isn‘t the question behind the question rather „how can I connect DosBox on macOS to the Internet“?

Comment: How did you accomplish "On your linux box install pppd and socat" on macOS?

Comment: @JeanRostan: I actually did it, but this is overkill. The VM was big af (2GB Debian, 8GB ElementaryOS) and it did work, but like you said, not really an anwser.

Comment: @nohillside: the DOSBox does connect, through PPP and virtual serial ports on it (as stated in DOSBox docs), but the problem is to redirect the traffic to the internet used by the host computer (in this case, the macOS). To install pppd and socat on macOS, I used homebrew to install socat but pppd was already preinstalled with macOS.